# Is it possible to implement reinforcement learning using a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, function-approximation

I've implemented [the reinforcement learning algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) for an agent to play [snappy bird](https://github.com/admonkey/snappybird) (a shameless cheap ripoff of flappy bird) utilizing a q-table for storing the history for future lookups. It works and eventually achieves perfect convergence after enough training.

Is it possible to implement a neural network to do function approximation in order to accomplish the purpose of the q-table? Obviously, storage is a concern with the q-table, but it doesn't seem to ever train with the neural net alone. Perhaps training the NN on an existing q-table would work, but I would like to not use a q-table at all if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Andrej Karpathy's blog](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/) has a tutorial on getting a neural network to learn pong with reinforcement learning. His commentary on the current state of the field is interesting.

He also provides a whole bunch of links (David Silver's [course](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html) catches my eye). [Here is a working link to the lecture videos.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pWv7GOvuf0)

Here are demos of DeepMinds game playing.
Get links to the papers at Andrej Karpathy's blog above
- [rat fps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAMuNUixKJ8)

- [nice demos at 19 minutes into this](http://livestream.com/oxuni/StracheyLectureDrDemisHassabis/videos/113380152)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The field of *deep reinforcement learning* is all about using deep neural networks (that is, neural networks with at least one hidden layer) to *approximate* value functions (such as the $Q$ function) or policies.

Have a look at the paper [A Brief Survey of Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05866) that gives a brief survey of the field.